# Ocaml utop does not (but does) recognise Big_int

Tags: ocaml, libraries, biginteger, utop, ocaml-dune

I have some code that uses the module `Big_int`, like in:

```
open Big_int;;
Big_int.gcd_big_int 5 6;;
```

However, when I compile this with utop `dune utop --release` (I use `release` to avoid some warnings), then I get this error:

`` Error: Required module `Big_int' is unavailable ``

I have read about it and I have read (https://groups.google.com/g/felix-language/c/1CfHgpe9zps?pli=1) that 'Big_int is no longer part of the OCaml distribution. It was replaced by Zarith'. Well, I know that, but also that I can still use `Big_int`.

How do I know it? The point is that if I start `utop` with any other file that has no errors, and once inside I open `Big_int`, then it does not regret:

`utop # open Big_int;;`

Once there, it autocompletes my `Big_int.`, like in `Big_int.add_big_int`. So there `Big_int` is there somewhere and it is recognised (VSCode also autocompletes it).

There is something I am not understanding. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For compatibility reasons, the binary files for the `num` library are still installed (in 2021) in the compiler directory. This is what you are seeing in utop.

However, `num` is deprecated in favor of `Zarith`.

If for some imperious needs, you need to use `num`, you need to declare it as a dependency in your project's dune file before using it with `dune utop`.

Comment: I see... I do not understand this: 'declare it as a dependency in your project's dune before using it'. You mean as a whole directory or something?

Comment: The entry in the `dune` file corresponding to your library must declare its dependency on `num`:
(library
  (name libname)
  (libraries num ... )
  ....
)

Comment: That works!! Lots of thanks. One last question, please. I am inside utop: ```utop #...``` and therefore I can use any of the libraries that have been charged on its files, like ```num```. Now, how can I call a function of any of my files that have been charged? Like in ```Big_int.add_big_int``` I have tried ```my_file.one_function```, but it does not work.

Comment: By default `dune` wraps modules inside a library module etrnypoint. Thus you need to use `Libname.My_file.f`

Comment: Completely fine. Thanks!